# creating a new variable based on if-then conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two numeric columns in python. 'value_BF_2016' and 'value_BF_2015'

I want to create a column which is 1 if both the previous cols are > 0 and 0 if not.

I can't seem to find this though I thought it would be straightforward. Might be my SAS/SQL background not quite getting it.

I've speculatively tried

```
dataset.['both_BF'] = (dataset['value_BF_2016'] > 0) &(dataset['value_BF_2015'] > 0)
```

and

```
dataset.ix[dataset['value_BF_2016'] > 0 & dataset['value_BF_2015'] > 0, 'Both_BF'] == 0
```

Comment: Apart from the dot before `[` in your first guess, what doesn't work about it? The idea looks right to me.

Comment: I assume this is for pandas?

Comment: @PeterWood `&` is valid python. This is the bitwise and operator, which is overridden in pandas.. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: Ahhh, the dot! Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra dot (`.`) in you first line of code.  Additionally, it will return a column of boolean values.  You can convert to `int` by multiplying by 1.

```
dataset['both_BF'] = 1*((dataset['value_BF_2016'] > 0) & 
                        (dataset['value_BF_2015'] > 0))
```

Comment: Change the `&` into `and`. The ampersand is for binary calculations.

Comment: I still get true/false when I do this and changing to and changing the & to and gives ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: & is correct with pandas. They have implemented this operator specifically for these purposes. You can convert the column to int by using `astype(int)`.